# $x_n = ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} )^n - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let :$$x_n = \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$

i know that :

$$\lim_n \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n:=e:=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\tag{1}$$

I will prove that this sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent to zero . (**without using log and $(1)$**)

---

I can not .please help me .

Comment: Can you use binomial theorem?

Comment: @Biggs. how...?

Comment: @Almot1960 $\left ( 1+x \right )^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$

Comment: If you know that $a_n \to e$ and $b_n \to e$ then you must have $a_n -b_n \to 0$.

Comment: Erm... sorry? Nobody can do that without (1)!

Comment: See theorem 3.31 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: @AymanHourieh If you have an helpful idea you can post an answer.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: that is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the binomial theorem
$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right) \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that for any $n\geq 2$ we have, by setting $b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$,
$$b_n-a_n=-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left[1-\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\right]\tag{2} $$
The coefficient between square brackets is an element of $(0,1)$ and for any fixed $k\geq 1$ we have that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[1-\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\right]=0$. By the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) it follows that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0$ as wanted.